# Sparklyr copy_to fails

Tags: r, hadoop, apache-spark, sparklyr

I am using the Sparklyr library to read and write data from R to HDFS. Reading data works as expected but writing gives issues.

To be able to use the spark_write_csv function, I need to convert my R data.frames into Spark objects. 
I use the sparklyr sdf_copy_to function for this (also tried with copy_to). However, I always get errors

Code:

```
table1 <- sdf_copy_to(sc,dataframe,OVERWRITE=TRUE)
spark_write_csv(table1, "path")
```

Error:

> Error: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does
>   not exist:
>   hdfs://iacchadoopdev01.dap:8020/tmp/Rtmp2gpelH/spark_serialize_62547a7b0f9ad206fd384af04e585deb3a2636ca7b1f026943d4cc1d11c7759a.csv

Did somebody encountered the same problem and knows how to solve this?

A possible reason might be that the sdf_copy_to function stores the data onto my linux /tmp folder while the write function is looking for data on the HDFS /tmp folder.

Comment: Don't know if it has anything to do with the issue (probably not) but shouldn't `OVERWRITE` be lowercase?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just tried overwrite in lowercase but gave the same error.

Comment: Could you try with the name of the Spark DataFrame (`"dataframe"` here?) instead of `table1` (name of the R wrapper)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You need to put the .csv into hdfs.
You can do this via the shell.

You logg into your cluster via ssh. Then you use 'put' to put the .csv into hdfs.

Write in the shell after you connected to the cluster:

hdfs dfs  'path to local file/file.csv' put 'path to folder in hdfs of your choosing'

Then you will use the hdfs path to load the file.